# Adding value to list initialize list size

Tags: java, list

I have below code:

```
Hashtable<Integer, List<Model>> map = new Hashtable<Integer, List<Model>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylistAssignment.size(); i++) {
        List<Model> temp = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < arraylistModel.size(); j++) {
            if (arraylistAssignment.get(i).getId() == arraylistModel.get(j)
                    .getId()) {
                if (temp == null)
                    temp = new ArrayList<Model>();// DEBUG POINT 1

                temp.add(arraylistModel.get(j)); 

            }// DEBUG POINT 2 AFTER ADD FUNCTION ABOVE

        }

        map.put(arraylistAssignment.get(i).getId(), temp);

    }
```

In the above code at debug point 1 when when i hv intitilzed the temp variable , there the object size is 0 as showm below :

[image]

but as soon as i add i.e temp.add the size is 1 but objects create is 12 out of which 11 values are null as shown below ...i could not understand the reason for null values here can anyone plz exaplin ...m i initilzing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you try attaching ArrayList's source and debug inside `ArrayList`'s constructor and `add()` and see from where it goes to 12 from 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), what means that it grows as elements are added. But it doesn't change its size *"one by one"*. Its size grows a "reasonable" amount, so the operation of resizing the list is not repeated each time you add an element, because this would be inefficient.

Comment: so i cannot get rid of that null values?

Comment: No, because it's business of the internal implementation of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: ok , but i m still unclear y it took the size of arrylistModel variable even if i add new Model()

Comment: It doubles in size every time you hit the maximum capacity.

Comment: @user3580294 can you give the source where you got `12` as default value? I've tested it with Java 1.7 and I get `10`.

Comment: Indeed it is 10. No idea why it was 12 in OP's case then.

Comment: I guess OP is trolling by specifying initial capacity in debug. I See no Chance of default capacity to be changed without any Dokumentation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for `null` values is because that's how `ArrayList`s work on the inside. They start off with a blank array inside, and as you add things they resize themselves as they see fit. The reason the array is larger than the number of objects you put in is because it'd be highly inefficient to resize the array every time you added something, so instead the `ArrayList` implementers just made the inner array start off at a certain size and approximately double in size every time it needs to be resized. They track how many elements you put in by tracking a separate `size` variable.

So in other words, you're initializing things just fine. Don't worry about the internals of the `ArrayList` -- if you look at the internal `size` variable, you'll see that it is `1`, just as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is a data structure in the `Collections` framework which is built on top of arrays I.e. It's implementation is done with the help of arrays. Since size is to be defined in arrays, *it initializes size to be 10 at first*. When you add values, it becomes the 11th item.

Now you might wonder **how is this dynamic** and how it works, well when size is reached to its limit it creates a new array double the size, copies the old stuff and discards the prev array. Would recommend you to take a look at the implementation.

To the user, it looks like dynamic but when you look through debugger you would see nulls. Array STARTS at 0 to 10 which makes it 11 elements and your newly added item becomes 12th but for public api, it's still the first element.

Check here for complete implementation of ArrayList: [link](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f)

Answer (score 0):

From Java Dokumentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

Default capacity is somehow 12 in your case, even though it should be 10.

Comment: Where did you got it's 12? Just asking, because according to JDK 7, default capacity is 10. Why can it be different from OP's code? Maybe the version?

Comment: I've tested it with Java 1.7 and I got `10` as the default value.